# getting nested attributes through strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model Actes and a model Keywords that are habtm in relation to each other.

When sending the new acte form to the server, I can't get through the strong parameters.

This is in `params[:acte]`  :

```
"acte"=>{
         "biblio_id"=>"1", 
         "acte_numero"=>"12", 
         "keywords_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"keyword"=>"attestation, "}},
         "texte"=>"<p>test</p>", 
         "complement"=>""
        }
```

model acte.rb contains:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :keywords
belongs_to :user, optional: true
belongs_to :biblio, optional: true
belongs_to :archive, optional: true
has_many :comments

accepts_nested_attributes_for :keywords, allow_destroy: true,
```

Note: if I add `reject_if: :all_blank` to `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, then the form doesn't get sent at all.

This is in acte_controller:

```
def params_acte
    params.require(:acte).permit(:biblio_id, 
                              :acte_numero, 
                              :keywords_attributes =>[:keyword],
                              : resume,
                              # cut for brievity
```

This provokes a `syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => :resume, ^`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the `keywords_attributes` at last.

```
def params_acte
    params.require(:acte).permit(:biblio_id, 
                                 :acte_numero, 
                                 :resume,
                                 # All other model attributes
                                 :keywords_attributes =>[:keyword],
```

This will work.

> NOTE: Always add nested attributes at the ending